# Getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError on running my code

Tags: java, android, abstractmethoderror

I am making a Java program that uses Appium. I get an error when I run my code. My code:

```
public class Base {

    public AndroidDriver driver;
    public AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    @Test
    public void configureAppium() throws Exception {

        service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withAppiumJS(new File(
                        "C:\\Users\\Sai Mada\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(300)).build();

        service.start();

        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName("My Demo");
        options.setApp(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\ApiDemos-debug.apk");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(13));
        driver.quit();
        service.stop();

    }

}
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
Appium_Demo.Appium_Demo.Base.configureAppium
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:491)
    at Appium_Demo.Appium_Demo.Base.configureAppium(Base.java:25)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:677)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

I know that error is thrown by Appium. I have tried to solve it in vain. Any solutions or help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: You have a version mismatch between the dependencies that provide `AppiumServiceBuilder` and `AppiumServiceBuilder`.  Check your dependencies.